# Error using FactoryGirl with has_secure_password in feature spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mongoid, factory-bot

Also using mongoid if that's relevant.

When I create a user with factory girl, it says the user is valid. However, when I access that user via ActiveRecord, is says it's invalid. Here's an overview of the issue:

```
user = create(:user, :activated)
user.valid? # => true
User.count # => 1
db_user = User.first
db_user == user # => true
db_user.valid? # => false
db_user.errors.count # => 0
# it only shows the error messages once I try to modify an attribute
db_user.email = "user@example.com"
db_user.save # => false
db_user.errors # => @messages={:password=>["is too short (minimum is 6 characters)", "can't be blank"]}
```

Here's my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    email { "#{name.gsub(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/i, '')}@example.com" }
    phone { Faker::Base.numerify("#{"#" * 10}") }
    admin false
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
  end
end
```

Here's the relevant parts of the User model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

  field :name,              type: String
  field :email,             type: String
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 },
                      presence: true
  has_secure_password
```

Comment: Update - this issue seems related to my problem https://github.com/mongoid-rspec/mongoid-rspec/issues/135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand how `has_secure_password` works internally:

When a user is created or its password should be changed, its `password` (and – depending on the configuration – a `password_confirmation`) attribute has to be set. But internally the `password` field is *not* stored in the database, but its value is hashed and stored in a database field named `password_digest`.

That means: When you load an existing user from the database, its `password` attribute will be `nil` (but `password_digest` should still be present). Therefore it will not be valid when you check such a user for the presence of a `password`.

To avoid this problem only validate for the presence of a password when creating a new user or if the user has a `password` that is not blank which means the user tries to update its password:

```
# there must be a password on create
validates :password, presence: true, on: :create

# the password must follow conventions when present (of example on update)
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true
```

Comment: This pretty much solves it, thanks! One thing to add is that the default validation still allows empty strings to be submitted via a password reset, so there should be an additional validation that checks that `password.nil? || password.present?` is true

Answer (score 0):

You're always running your additional validation.  `has_secure_password` already checks for the [password](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html).  So you don't need the presence validation.

You could simply make your validation conditional

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: Proc.new{|u| u.password_changed? }
```

Should work I think using ActiveModel::Dirty

If not you can just run the validation if it's present.

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: Proc.new{|u| u.password.present? }
```

Comment: It works when I take off all of the password validations, but it doesn't look like it's validating presence anymore.

Comment: `user = build(:user, password: "      ").valid?` returns true

Comment: Weird, it should according to the rails api.  You can always add the presence validation back in if you can't track down why it's not working.

Comment: Oh, I should've mentioned -- the moment I add the presence validation back, the original issue starts to occur again

Answer (score -1):

I decided to take a look at the ["Rails Tutorial - Adding a secure password"](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#sec-adding_a_secure_password) section by Michael Hartl. I saw that he wrote the code with `has_secure_password` **before** `validates`, as shown below:

```
has_secure_password
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

Try changing the order of and see if that works. I have note tested it but this is one of the main resources I used when I was starting out and it worked for me in the past. Good Luck.

Comment: Doesn't work, even after changing the order. I think I found an unresolved github issue about the problem I'm having that I added to the post.

Comment: @ben-muschol can you please add a link to the Github issue in case other users are experiencing the same problem? Thank you.

Comment: It's in a comment on the post, here's the link: https://github.com/mongoid-rspec/mongoid-rspec/issues/135